# Tunnel git request from server trough user's computer

Tags: git, ssh

the company I work for is using a self-hosted gitlab at `gitlab.company.net`. The gitlab is only accessible from within the company network. I also have a company server which is not in the company network.
I would like to be able to work with git on the server, as manually copying files back and forth during development is very cumbersome. Ideally the solution would also work for different users, i.e. depending on who is working on the server the connection gets tunneled through their computer. So far I tried to make it work with SSH tunneling, but I am not sure if it is possible or if I am doing something wrong.

On the server I configured the git to use `localhost` as proxy for gitlab.company.net:

```
git config --global http.https://gitlab.company.net.proxy localhost:4443
```

I login with ssh using:

```
ssh -R 4443:gitlab.company.net:443 -i keyfile user@server-ip
```

So my hope was that with the proxy setting the request gets redirected to localhost and from there to my computer because of the `-R` option, which then redirects it to `gitlab.company.net`.
It seems to do something as I get different responses when trying to clone depending on whether I am logged into the company network:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.company.net/...': Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT
```

or not:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.company.net/...': Failed to connect to localhost port 4443 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This does not work either. I also do not think it is correct. The `-L` option is used to ["to forward a port from the client machine to the server machine"](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example#local-forwarding). I am trying to forward a port from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not make it work with https cloning but I found the solution for ssh [here](https://rse.shef.ac.uk/blog/2019-01-31-ssh-forwarding/).

You need to connect to the server with `-R port:gitlab.company.net:22`, e.g.:

```
ssh -R 2020:gitlab.company.net:22 -i keyfile user@server-ip
```

And on the server you can then clone by replacing `gitlab.company.net` with `localhost` and also specifying the port number, e.g.:

```
git clone ssh://git@localhost:2020/....
```